# openssl.conf: How to limit the list of offered cipher suites as a client on openssl?

Tags: encryption, openssl, client, tls1.3

I want to limit the offered cipher suites in the client_hello to just one and enforce this cipher suite for TLS negotiation in openssl.conf.

I was already trying the following settings but still a lot of ciphers are offered:

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_section

[ssl_section]
system_default = system_default_section

[system_default_section]
Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Can anybody help?